# Calling a dynamically named text input box php

Tags: php, loops, dynamic, text, naming

This is the naming code that I have:

```
    <?php
    for ($i=1; $i<=$housingcount; $i++){
      echo '<input onchange="myFunction(value)" size="',11,'" type="text" name="cavqty',$i,'" id="hous',$i,'"/>';}
    ?>
```

Where `$housingcount` is simply the number of rows queried from the database (`$housingcount=mysql_num_rows($result)`).

And myFunction isn't really important for the context of this question because it's just a simple summing function, but anyway it looks like this:

```
    <script>
    function myFunction(tBox)
    {
    var sum=0;
    var elts = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for (var i=0; i<elts.length; i++) {
      var elt=elts[i];
        if ( elt.id && elt.id.indexOf('hous')===0 sum += Number(elt.value);
    document.getElementById('sum').innerText=sum;
    }
    </script>
```

So based on the php code the number of text boxes changes based on the number of housings in this case. Therefore the text boxes are named dynamically (cavqty1, cavqty2, cavqty3,...) as a result of which iteration the loop is on. Now this naming method has caused a lot of trouble for me because I have no idea how to call the text box names in order to use them for another function.

Upon research I thought that I would have to force them into an array and look through each individual row one by one by using a foreach statement but that didn't work. Alas, I am very stumped by this whole dynamic naming thing.

My question for you is: how do I call the dynamically named text boxes, so I can use them in other functions?

Comment: Your `if` statement is not correctly closed..if not a typo

Comment: Did you know there is an HTML syntax error on the `name` property?

Comment: alright the javascript part of this code works fine probably just typos on that because I wasn't really worried about it due to the fact that it isn't really relevant here. It was more put in there just for people asking what myFunction is

Comment: @Flosculus no I don't get a syntax error on the name property

Comment: @Flosculus Oh you were right I missed the equal sign. Sorry typo

Comment: @user2618927 This `funciton myFunction(tBox)` typo? `function` as in `function myFunction(tBox)` ;-)

Comment: @Fred yea i'll get that

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<?php
for ($i=1; $i<=$housingcount; $i++){
    echo '<input onchange="myFunction(value)" size="',11,'" type="text" name="cavqty[]" id="hous',$i,'"/>';
}
?>
```

Then on the other side you can use:

```
if(isset($_POST["cavqty"])){
    foreach($_POST["cavqty"] as $cavqty){
        echo $cavqty;
    }
}
```

Or simply: `$_POST["cavqty"][0]` for specific values.

Comment: it says undefined index and warning: invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: I don't want specific values I need to be able to pull all values with that name prefix

Comment: I've edited it, try now. Also do you really need to increment the id? Why not just use a class.

Comment: I have no idea. Bottom line is I want to be able to run a function that validates all of these text box inputs and submits them but as of now I have no way of accessing the text boxes

Comment: and it is still an undefined index for cavqty

Comment: You're using `if(isset($_POST["cavqty"]))` to catch the post right?

Comment: I am but maybe my isset function is wrong. How would you write it just to see if the catch is working?

Comment: Okay there is no error now, so how would I print the data in the text box now?

Comment: or to reword that what can I do to visually show that it works?

Comment: okay that's what I thought just to use echo. There is no error on the page but nothing echoes

Comment: Do `var_dump($_POST);`

Comment: I appreciate all of your help, but I think I will just try another method. Thank you for your time